# Changing Localized nib file on click of a button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to internationalize my application. In have localized my application properly and the language of the application gets change on changing the iPhone language from settings but what I want is that the application's language should be changed in running application on click of a button (i have defined two buttons, one for english and one for turkish).

I am using below code to change the language.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//localization

self.usernameLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"UserName", nil);
self.passwordLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PassWord", nil);
self.loginLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Login", nil);


english.tag=ENGLSIH_LANGUAGE;
turkish.tag=TURKISH_LANGUAGE;

currentLanguage=ENGLSIH_LANGUAGE;}



-(IBAction) languageChanged:(id)sender{

UIButton *clickedButton=(UIButton *)sender;

switch (clickedButton.tag) {
    case ENGLSIH_LANGUAGE:
        currentLanguage=ENGLSIH_LANGUAGE;

        NSLog(@"Language Changed ");

        break;
    case TURKISH_LANGUAGE:
        currentLanguage=TURKISH_LANGUAGE;

        NSLog(@"Language Changed ");

        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

How can I achieve that and load the localized nib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To internationalize your application, try this link, it will be helpful for you

[Internationalizing the application on the fly](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html)

Comment: thanx, this example helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change language while app is running.